# Can not install SQL Server 2016 on the Windows Server 2008 R2 Core

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I am trying to install SQL Server 2016 on the Windows Server 2016 Core. As it does not have graphical interface, I am doing it from the command line. This is the command I am using:

> Setup.exe /qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine,Replication
>   /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="WORKGROUP\MyUser"
>   /SQLSVCPASSWORD="MySecretPass"
>   /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="WORKGROUP\MyUser" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT
>   AUTHORITY\Network Service" /TCPENABLED=1 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS

And this is the error log file I am getting:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643838
  Exit facility code:            1203
  Exit error code:               2
  Exit message:                  No features were installed during the setup execution. The requested features may already be installed. Please review the summary.txt log for further details.
  Start time:                    2015-08-27 06:37:53
  End time:                      2015-08-27 06:41:39
  Requested action:              Install

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  WIN-4EPO0BFRBMJ
  Machine processor count:       1
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2008 R2 - ServerCore
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview 2.2 (CTP2.2)
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016 CTP2.2
  Type:                          CTP
  Version:                       13
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         X:\Downloads\SQLServer2016CTP2.2-x64-ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Evaluation

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150827_063736\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                true
  FEATURES:                      
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    <empty>
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   true
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 WORKGROUP\MyUser
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           WORKGROUP\MyUser>
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            0
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  true
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150827_063736\ConfigurationFile.ini

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150827_063736\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.NoopWorkflowException
    Message: 
        No features were installed during the setup execution. The requested features may already be installed. Please review the summary.txt log for further details.
    HResult : 0x84b30002
        FacilityCode : 1203 (4b3)
        ErrorCode : 2 (0002)
```

UPDATED:
tried installation with the **windows server core 2012** the errors are the same, but there are summary.txt

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2061762559
  Exit facility code:            1308
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  Account 'WORKGROUP\Administrator' provided for service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' does not exist. Provide an existing account name for the service.
  Start time:                    2015-08-28 11:58:53
  End time:                      2015-08-28 12:00:50
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for AS:              SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for IS:              SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Conn:            SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for ComponentUpdate: SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC:            SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC_SDK:        SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Writer:          SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.
  Next step for Browser:         SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  SQL-PC
  Machine processor count:       1
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2012 - ServerCore
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview 2.2 (CTP2.2)
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016 CTP2.2
  Type:                          CTP
  Version:                       13
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         X:\Downloads\SQLServer2016CTP2.2-x64-ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Evaluation

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 WORKGROUP\Administrator
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config
  ASDATADIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            WORKGROUP\Administrator /ASSERVERMODE=TABULAR /TCPENABLED=1 /ACTION=Install
  ASTEMPDIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                true
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, AS, CONN, IS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MsDtsServer130
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   true
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 WORKGROUP\Administrator
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           WORKGROUP\Administrator
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  true
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150828_115850\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Analysis Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Integration Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Setup Support Files
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            Setup was canceled for the feature.
  Next Step:                     SQL Server Setup was canceled before completing the operation. Try the setup process again.

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150828_115850\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingValidationException
    Message: 
        Account 'WORKGROUP\Administrator' provided for service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' does not exist. Provide an existing account name for the service.
    HResult : 0x851c0001
        FacilityCode : 1308 (51c)
        ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
    Data: 
      SQL.Setup.FailureCategory = InputSettingValidationFailure
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.LogAllValidationErrorsAndThrowFirstOne(ValidationState vs)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.ValidateFeatureSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClasse.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__b()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
    Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Agent.InputValidationException
        Message: 
                Account 'WORKGROUP\Administrator' provided for service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' does not exist. Provide an existing account name for the service.
        HResult : 0x851c0001
                FacilityCode : 1308 (51c)
                ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
```

Comment: For starters, Win2008 OS is not even supported.  Not saying that is the issue, but I would try a different OS first.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.130).aspx#pmosr

Comment: tried with windows 2012. It is the same. As far as I understand I've messed up something with users in the command line...

Comment: what is in summary.txt file?

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: `Account 'WORKGROUP\Administrator' provided for service 'SQLSERVERAGENT' does not exist.`

Comment: yes, I see the message, but I do not really understand it. I have windows account Administrator. I do not have domain, but I have workgroup. What do I need to create or what do I need to modify in the installation script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my own question. The problem was in the domain. As I didn't have domain I needed to use computer name instead of the WORKGROUP.

UPDATED: I also found much easier way to install it:

> setup.exe /UIMODE=EnableUIOnServerCore /Action=install
>   /INDICATEPROGRESS=True

Comment: that kinda defeatsthe purpose of using command line install. If you're gonna walk the GUI manually, then just run setup.exe without the parameters. If you want to simplify/standardize installation configuration, only values for the REQUIRED parameters and for parameters you want to customize. Details on what's available and what parameters are required vs optional are found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Comment: Running setup.exe without parameters does not work on Windows Server CORE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing using a local account then you need to put the account name as MACHINE NAME\ACCOUNT as you pointed out in your last post. Even if your machine is on a domain, you will have to follow the same naming convention. To get more verbose output for troubleshooting while the setup is running you can use INDICATEPROGRESS setup parameter without having to switch to UI mode.